# Getting Yaw of hand unstable

Tags: leap-motion

I am making a puppet app with the Leap Motion. Whenever I try and get the Yaw of a hand it always seems to be wrong (ie: My hand is flat but it says its at 45 degrees or my hand is flat and it says its at -30 degrees, generally unreliable and jumpy). I use

```
    Hand hand = frame.hands().get(0);

    palm1Position = hand.palmPosition();

    normal = hand1.palmNormal();
    direction = hand1.direction();

    palmRoll = Math.toDegrees(normal1.roll());
    palmYaw = Math.toDegrees(direction1.yaw());
```

To get the Roll and Yaw of the hand. The roll works perfectly but the yaw is horrible. This is a problem because marionettes rely heavily on yaw. Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a quite good Yaw-value, however my Roll-values aren't usable... Perhaps we have weird hands ;)

Comment: Noah also asked this on the Leap Motion developer forum. It turned out he was confusing yaw for pitch.

Comment: Yes I did, the good old 1:00 am brain wasn't quite working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in JavaScript and I don't think we have this yet, but the Java docs say you should have this

```
float pitch = hand.direction().pitch();
float yaw = hand.direction().yaw();
float roll = hand.palmNormal().roll();
```

See https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Java/Guides/Leap_Tracking.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the yaw of your hand, why don't get the vector of the middle Finger? Or maybe the average of all the fingers of the hand?

I don't know if the results will be better but I think it can worth testing.

And what is the language you are using? Java?